# Try-catch prompting incorrect messages

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm working on a program that asks the user to introduce two integers to be added and return it. In case that at least one of them is not an integer, the program will keep asking for two valid inputs, and then adding them.
Here's my code

```
package org.ip.sesion08;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EntradaEnterosConExcepcion {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);       
        int number1 = 0;
        int number2 = 0;
        boolean error = false;
        while(!error){
            try{
        // Introducir dos enteros
                System.out.print("Introduzca dos valores enteros: ");
                number1 = entrada.nextInt();
                number2 = entrada.nextInt();
                error = true;       

            }
            catch (InputMismatchException ne){
                System.out.print("Incorrecto, introduzca dos valores enteros: ");
                entrada.next();
                entrada.next();


            }
        }
            System.out.println("La suma es  " + (number1 + number2));
            }

        }
```

My problem is that, after I input something invalid (like a 2), the program shows me the message from the catch and the one from the try inmediately after.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, how can I avoid showing the message from the try again?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you trying to grab input again inside the catch??

Comment: Which message "from the try" are you referring to? Could you please share your output?

Comment: You could store the message as a variable and update it in the catch.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get the expected result if put the message outside the while loop. The following might work,

```
package org.ip.sesion08;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EntradaEnterosConExcepcion {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);       
    int number1 = 0;
    int number2 = 0;

    // Introducir dos enteros
    System.out.print("Introduzca dos valores enteros: ");
    boolean error = false;
    while(!error){
        try{

            number1 = entrada.nextInt();
            number2 = entrada.nextInt();
            error = true;       

        }
        catch (InputMismatchException ne){
            System.out.print("Incorrecto, introduzca dos valores enteros: ");

        }
    }
        System.out.println("La suma es  " + (number1 + number2));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the next token available from the input cannot be interpreted as an `int`, then `Scanner.nextInt()` throws an `InputMismatchException`, which you catch.  The token that causes this remains unscanned, so it is reasonable for your catch block to scan and reject *one* token, but not two.  You are discarding the token immediately following the bad one, too, without even examining it.

Afterward, execution will certainly cycle back to the top of the loop, exactly as you apparently intend.  It will re-enter the `try` block, and therefore print the prompt again.  If you want to avoid printing the prompt again, then move it to just before the loop.

Note, however, that your program requires two consecutive numbers to be entered.  If you enter a number and then a non-number, the initial number is forgotten when you loop back.  You might want to consider performing an input loop such as you have on a per-token basis, instead of two at a time.  You might, for instance, use a single loop whose exit condition measures how many numbers have successfully been entered.  That would go well with using an array or List to record the numbers, instead of separate variables.